# using alisas in mysql if statements

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find which of two specified rows in one table costCentreClientGroups has the most related records in another table costCentreClientGroupMembership

So I have

```
SELECT IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
db6901371_clients.costCentreClientGroupMembership c1
JOIN db6901371_clients.costCentreClientGroups c2 
ON c1.costCentreClientGroupID = c2.costCentreClientGroupID
WHERE c2.costCentreClientGroupID = '1a64fa70-aa0d-11e4-8c36-776ec28246d8' 
GROUP BY c2.costCentreClientGroupID) > 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db6901371_clients.costCentreClientGroupMembership c3
JOIN db6901371_clients.costCentreClientGroups c4 
ON c3.costCentreClientGroupID = c4.costCentreClientGroupID
WHERE c4.costCentreClientGroupID = '1a7582f0-aa0d-11e4-8c36-776ec28246d8' 
GROUP BY c4.costCentreClientGroupID)
, c2.costCentreClientLeaderID, c4.costCentreClientLeaderID)
as costCentreClientLeaderID
```

Individually the IF clauses work

So;

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db6901371_clients.costCentreClientGroupMembership c1
JOIN db6901371_clients.costCentreClientGroups c2 
ON c1.costCentreClientGroupID = c2.costCentreClientGroupID
WHERE c2.costCentreClientGroupID = '1a64fa70-aa0d-11e4-8c36-776ec28246d8' 
GROUP BY c2.costCentreClientGroupID
```

works

but when I combine the two the overall statement gives

Unknown table 'c2' in field list

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the use of the subqueries.  You are using an alias *after* the closing paren of the subquery, so the alias is out-of-scope.  That is, it is not recognized.

You can fix this by moving the subqueries to the `from` clause.  My preference is to change to the query to use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN SUM(g.costCentreClientGroupID = '1a64fa70-aa0d-11e4-8c36-776ec28246d8') >
                  SUM(g.costCentreClientGroupID = '1a7582f0-aa0d-11e4-8c36-776ec28246d8')
            THEN MAX(CASE WHEN g.costCentreClientGroupID = '1a64fa70-aa0d-11e4-8c36-776ec28246d8'
                          THEN g.costCentreClientLeaderID
                     END)
            ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN g.costCentreClientGroupID = '1a7582f0-aa0d-11e4-8c36-776ec28246d8'
                          THEN g.costCentreClientLeaderID
                     END)
      END)
FROM db6901371_clients.costCentreClientGroupMembership gm JOIN
     db6901371_clients.costCentreClientGroups g
     ON gm.costCentreClientGroupID = g.costCentreClientGroupID
WHERE g.costCentreClientGroupID IN ('1a64fa70-aa0d-11e4-8c36-776ec28246d8', '1a7582f0-aa0d-11e4-8c36-776ec28246d8')
```

It is not obvious why that table `costCentreClientGroupMembership` is needed in the query.  It does not seem to be used.

Comment: Thanks. That should work. costCentreClientGroupMembership is included because I want to extract a UUID from this table. But I can work it from here. Again thanks.

Comment: I tested this and it always returns  the last row regardless of the logical operator i.e. > or < costCentreClientGroupMembership is needed in the query because I am trying to compare related records in this table